# Getting a null reference exception trying to push a zero to a stack

Tags: vb.net, stack, push, nullreferenceexception

Well I am on my last day of school trying to finish a program and I can't for the life of me get past this null reference exception. My code is supposed to average together [count] numbers entered by the user using a stack of Integers. It was throwing a null reference exception because it attempted to get the count of the stack which was empty, so I added the line to Push a zero on to it. The program now stops at that line with the same error (nullreferenceexception). If I change the stack to accept Strings it works fine, but I need it to accept Integers. Thanks for anyone who can help :)

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim count As Integer = 16
        Dim stack As New Stack(Of Integer)
        stack.Push(0)
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter " & count & " numbers")
        Do While stack.Count - 1 = count
            stack.Push(Console.ReadLine)
            If Not IsNumeric(stack.Peek) Then
                Console.WriteLine(stack.Pop & " is not a number please try again.")
            End If
        Loop
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: There are a couple of other problems here too. ReadLine returns a string, but you're applying the value to a stack that takes an integer.. IsNumeric is only valid on a string, but you're giving it an Integer value.

Comment: I see that, what I am planning on doing is putting the stack.Push in a Try Catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring a variable named `stack`, but you are not actually creating a `Stack` object. Do this instead (with the `New` keyword):

```
Dim stack As New Stack(Of Integer)
```

Without `New`, the variable will contain a null reference, which is why you were getting the `NullReferenceException` whenever you attempt to do anything with that variable.

Comment: Well I tried that and now it appears to crash on the Do While line

Comment: Perhaps `Do While stack.Count < count` is what you're going for?

Comment: Yeah actually, I can't believe I missed that. Probably school stress. Thank you a lot for the help :)